# MySQL,PHP: ORDER BY shoots an error.

Tags: php

Whenever I try to use ORDER BY I'm getting an error saying that it's something bad with syntax

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id' at line 1

For me, the syntax looks perfectly good, everything works as long as I don't use ORDER BY id. This is how it works:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons $limit";
```

This is how I want it to work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons $limit ORDER BY id";
```

I have also tried this, but with no luck:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons $limit ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: Whatever `$limit` is, it is not SQL compatible

Comment: The $limit is fine and everything works when I'm not using ORDER BY so it's ORDER BY who is causing error.

Comment: Prove me wrong. What is in `$limit`?

Comment: Append the `LIMIT` clause after `ORDER BY`

Comment: $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 
$pagenum = 1;
$page_rows = 25;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY` needs to go before `LIMIT`.

Try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lessons ORDER BY id $limit";
```

Comment: Thanks, That's the right answer,I'll accept it in 6 minutes.